# How to add a PPA

Tags: 14.04, apt, ppa

I wish to add the 14.04 GQRX PPA, how can this be achieved?

https://launchpad.net/~gqrx/+archive/ubuntu/releases

Answer (score 1):

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gqrx/releases` and then `sudo apt-get update` should add it.

Comment: Cheers,  Why cant they say that, instead of being all (Linux about it :)

Comment: @PeterJohnson I don't know. The tutorials on the official Ubuntu page always too hard to follow. If this is the answer, could you mark it as such (checkmark below vote buttons)?